# Linq fetch distinct

Tags: c#, linq, random, distinct

I have the query:

```
var q = (
    from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
    where
    itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
    && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
    select c
);
```

It will return something along the lines of:

```
ID    ItemID    RecommendItemID    Message
------------------------------------------
1     25        3                  Msg here
2     26        3                  Something else
3     27        8                  Another message
```

I need the query to filter out results that have the same `RecommendItemID`, this should not appear in returned results more than once.

If two exist, it can use either (random selection would be best).  So the returned results should omit record ID 1 or 2.

Can anyone show me how to do this please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to use GroupBy and then select the first item from each group:

```
var q = (
    from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
    where
        itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
     && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
    select c
).GroupBy(c => c.RecommendItemID)
 .Select(g => g.First());
```

---

If you're using this to display a random review, I would recommend foisting this into the using code rather than the LINQ query, by omitting the `First` like so:

```
var q = (
    from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
    where
        itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
     && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
    select c
).GroupBy(c => c.RecommendItemID)
 .Select(g => g.ToArray());

var random = new Random();
foreach (var r in q)
{
    var rec = r[random.Next(r.Length)];
    // use your recommendation
}
```

Comment: Great thanks!  One problem though, it doesn't randomise the duplicate to return.  Any ideas on this one?

Comment: @TomGullen: and I've provided another way (less LINQ for the random choice).

Comment: good answer. but can anyone enlighten me as to why `var rec = r.Length == 1 ? r[0] : r[random.Next(r.Length)];` is required? `random.Next` returns a number between zero (inclusive) and length (exclusive) anyway...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can add a distinct comparison to the end of your linq expression, like:

```
var q = (
  from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
  where
  itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
  && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
  select c
)
.Distinct((x, y) => x.RecommendItemID == y.RecommendItemID);
```

---

*Edit*

I just realized I did this using an extension method that I wrote myself and typically keep handy... here is the code for it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a way to get a distinct list of items based on a lambda comparison operator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="equalityComparer">A comparison function that returns true of the two items are considered equal.</param>
    /// <returns>The list of distinct items.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> equalityComparer)
    {
        var distincts = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var found = false;
            foreach (var d in distincts)
            {
                found = equalityComparer(item, d);
                if (found)
                    break;
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                distincts.Add(item);
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<tblStoreRecommendation>`, not just use the lambda directly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: I believe the Distinct overload takes a type implementing `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` rather than a predicate.

Comment: Ah you are right, I typed this in to VisualStudio in an existing project, where I just happen to have my own extension method to do it... see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this sticking with the query expression as far along as possible:

```
var q = from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
        where itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
          && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
        group c by c.RecommendItemID into matches
        select matches.First();
```

The contextual keyword [`into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045.aspx) sure comes in handy here.

here's how to [randomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
```

---

```
var q = from c in db.tblStoreRecommendations
        where itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.ItemID)
          && !itemIDsInCart.Contains(c.RecommendItemID)
        group c by c.RecommendItemID
        into matches
        select matches.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(random.Next(matches.Count()));
```

Since LINQ to SQL can't handle the `ElementAt` call, I edited the answer to execute the query (by calling `AsEnumerable`) before choosing the Random element out of the grouping.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure how an L2S or L2E would handle the ElementAt/Count combination. You may need an AsEnumerable call in between the two to materialize the results.

Comment: good point, I don't have SQL server at home... can someone confirm this?

Comment: Thanks for this but I get the error `System.NotSupportedException: The query operator 'ElementAt' is not supported.`

Comment: thanks for the heads-up, could you try the modified code, as well? That should have fixed it. And thank you @sixlettervariables for the suggestion. Is there any easy way to test code like this without running SQL Server?

Comment: @codesparkle: not that I'm aware, besides reading through the obscure MSDN documentation on which works and which do not. (As an aside you'll need to make the entire query before the AsEnumerable a parenthetical.)